# Android ActionBar and Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard, android-actionbar

My android application uses a bluetooth pedal for hands free navigation.
The pedal - an AirTurn BT105 - registers itself as a hardware keyboard.

I can capture the keys sent by the pedal in my activity via `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)`, and everything works OK.

However, even though I return true when I intercept the key, the actionbar is also responding to the key event.
In my `ActionBar`, I have a series of `ImageView`s for specialised layout purposes.
The first `ImageView` is getting highlighted, as if it receives just an `ACTION_DOWN` message.
In addition, although the layout file specifies that the `ImageView` should not receive focus, when I look at it through the view hierarchy viewer, they are all stated as being focusable.

Is there a means to stop this behaviour ?

Can I intercept the navigation key events for the ActionBar window as well ?

**Note : using native ActionBar in Android 4.4.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this "problem", was to manually set the focusable property when building the actionbar menu.

1 - Get the actionview item with

```
View v = menu.findItem(itemId).getActionView();
```

2 - After having done your setup **and** enabled or disabled it, set the focusable values

```
v.setFocusable(false);
v.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

When enabled the user will still be able to tap / click on the widget and it will still respond.

I hope this helps someone, eventually